# iptables 4.12 IP not found: BASH function $line issue

Tags: bash, line, iptables

While creating a simple script that grabs a blacklist of ip addresses and blocks them, I came across this issue:

```
    ## Function giving greif
    function _droplist (){
    while read line; do

$IPT -A droplist -i eth1 -s $line -j LOG --log-prefix "IP BlockList "
$IPT -A droplist -i eth1 -s $line -j DROP

    done < $badlist    ##IPT is /sbin/iptables
    }
```

Through several iterations of this function I get the error:

```
    Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
    ' not found.4.12: host/network `SO.ME.IPH.ERE
```

Running the same script with hard coded in IP's works fine, its either something to do with $line or m implementation of iptables.

cheers -- Baffled.

Comment: Corrected the issue by: moving the iteration and passing back a variable like: $IPT -A INPUT -s $@ -j DROP ... still unsure if it was $line or the blacklist formatting?

Answer (score 1):

What does $badlist contain? A file name or a list of IPs?

if it's a filename it should work as you did it, but if it's a list of ip you have to change how you read them.

Assuming it's a new-line-delimited list of IPs like:

```
$ badlist="1.1.1.1\n2.2.2.2\n3.3.3.3" 
$ echo -e "$badlist"
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

then you have to modify the loop as follows:

```
$ echo -e "$badlist"|while read line; do 
    # do stuff with $line
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, the badlist was just that: a list of ipv4's the issue was that the list contained \r\r\n each line!

Answer (score 0):

This was an early dive into bash scripting for me the code was also placed remotely on a friends box, the last rough iteration I own of it is on my pastebin:

```
    #!/bin/bash
# ..
# ..
# ..

## Variables
stamp=$(date "+%d/%m/%Y %T")
seed="$RANDOM-$RANDOM-IPTABLES-$(date "+%d-%m-%Y")-TEMPORY"     ##  proverbial sandpit  
log=/root/.IPTables.log; touch $log                             ##  Always a logfile
dmp=/tmp/IPT_DUMP$seed.temp                                     ##  Intermediate
list=/tmp/IPT_LIST$seed.txt                                ##  F**ing '\r\r\n' regex'rs
pos=0

## Link(s)
link=http://au.hive.sshhoneypot.com/downloads/iplist.php


## Log File
function _tolog (){
        echo -e "$stamp - $@\r" >> $log
}

## Leadin'
_tolog "  "
_tolog "-----Running rottweiler : A simple IP deny auto script "
sh -c "iptables --flush"; _tolog "--OK Tables have been flushed"; sleep 1

## Grab-blacklist(s)            # Fortran array HO!
function _populate (){
        wget $link -O $dmp | egrep '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | xargs; _tolog "--OK blacklist stored from honeypot"
        tr -d '\r' < $dmp > $list # See above rage comment
        while read line; do
                arrayIp[$pos]=$line
                ((pos++))
        done < $list
        _tolog "--OK IP array created!"
        _tolog $(echo -e "---- Array size: ${#arrayIp[*]}")
        for item in ${arrayIp[*]}
        do
                 sh -c "/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s $item -j DROP"    # This drops the current blacklist
        done; _tolog "--OK Commands passed to iptables DB"           # Use: /sbin/iptables -L -v -n to get list back quickly ( no resolving crap )
        /sbin/iptables-save > /root/iptables.backup; _tolog "--OK Table database saved to flatfile"
}

_populate
_tolog  "-----Terminating script: Tables logged in ~/iptables.backup"
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues resulting from Windows line endings (\r\n). Converting to unix endings (\n) solved my problem.

Cheers, /phfff